# another / the other hand

Tags: word-choice

> She started shivering, so Jonas took her one hand, Father took **another** / **the other** and they comforted her.

***The other*** is definitely appropriate here. But what about ***another***? There is only one arm left, is it semantically correct to say *another* when refer to only one object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The other" is correct. To say "he took another hand" implies that she has more than two.

Also, you wouldn't say "took her one hand". That implies that she only has one hand. (Perhaps due to a birth defect or an accident?) You'd say, "took one of her hands" or simply "took her hand".

Comment: *Her one hand* is OK (albeit rather old-fashioned) in the context of *one ... other*; a parallel use, "on the one hand", is current.